# Labeling a point by giving its x and y axes on geom_histogram

Tags: r, histogram

How to show the point (x=0, y=1500) with a text label next to it on the following histogram?

```
ggplot(ds_visits, aes(x = patientsInService)) + 
    geom_histogram(stat = "count", col = "black", fill = "white") + 
    theme_bw() + 
    labs(x = "Patients in service", y = "Cases") + 
    scale_x_discrete(limits = seq(0, 5, 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create dummy `data.frame` for point data:

```
pointData <- data.frame(X = 0, Y = 1500)
```

Plot it with with two additional gems (`geom_point` and `geom_text`):

```
ggplot(ds_visits, aes(patientsInService)) + 
geom_histogram(stat = "count", col = "black", fill = "white") + 
geom_point(data = pointData, aes(X , Y)) +
geom_text(data = pointData, aes(X + 1 , Y + 10, label = "My Text"))
```

In `geom_text` I'm changing coordinates a little bit not to overlap text with point.